# How to convert a JAVA object into an HTML table?

Tags: java, html, serialization

I want a generic way to convert Java object to HTML table that contains the member variables of this object as the column name and the value of this member as a value in the table like this:

```
class Person {

    public String _name;
    public int _age;

    public Person(){
        this._name = "John Doe";
        this._age = 2;
    }
};
```

If the object of type person I want the output to be something like this.

```
---------------------------
|    _name   | _age        |
---------------------------

|    John Doe | 2          |
---------------------------
```

The problem is I don't have access to the classes code.

Is there a generic way to implement a function that can take a Java object of any type and print the member variable and its value?

I thought about using `toString()` but it didn't help since I can't override it in my case.

If this is the class

```
class Person {

    public String _name;
    public int _age;

    public Person(){
        this._name = "John Doe";
        this._age = 2;
    }
};
```

then `PrintobjectToHTML();` output is supposed to be

```
---------------------------
|    _name   | _age        |
---------------------------
|    John Doe |    2       |
---------------------------
```

Comment: you could try through reflection

Comment: There is an old library called [Jmesa](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jmesa/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using reflection. You can use the class Class for that (see-> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Example:

```
Person p = new Person();
Class cls = p.getClass();
Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
// loop through fields
for (Field field: fields) {
  Object value = field.get(p);
  // print value as html
}
```